# Should I use '==' for .NET localized string comparisons?

Tags: c#, .net, string, localization, comparison

What are the reasons not to use "==" to compare localized strings in .NET? How would the comparison execute in regards to the CultureInfo if I do use it?

Comment: Are you asking about the C# `==` operator?  If so, you should add the C# tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`==` is culture-insensitive - it's a simple ordinal comparison. So two strings which are culturally equal - or even equal in terms of other canonicalization forms - may *not* be equal via `==`. It basically treats each string like a `char` array.

Answer (score 14):

If you compare culture-aware strings with ==, for example "Strasse" with "Straße", it returns false.

If you need culture-aware comparings for UI stuff (Sorting of Listview), you use String.Compare with the related CultureInfo.

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
String.Compare("Strasse", "Straße", true, ci) // Returns zero
```

Answer (score 10):

The overloaded `String.operator ==` will perform an culture-unaware ordinal comparison – it compares the strings byte-by-byte using a [heavily optimized unrolled loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5927545/34397).
It calls the same internal function as `String.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.Ordinal)`