# Is it good practice to compare C# string with '=='?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Is it a good practice to compare strings with `==`? Is there an equivalent to `s1 == s2` in terms of `Compare` and `Equals` methods on `string`. If one uses those methods, without specifying `CultureInfo` FxCop will give a warning, is that a real problem?

Comment: What sort of compare do you want to do?

Comment: Depends on what you are comparing - the msdn is perfect for this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx

Comment: This page has a good explanation: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-equals

Comment: After you read that one read this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbh501kz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175935/using-for-net-localized-string-comparison/8175990) previous SO question of why `==` can be a bad idea depending on your context.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `==` Operator is an ordinal, culture unaware string compare. Its using the same internal call as `.Equals`, and is just fine for the "usual" string compare stuff.

If you need Culture-Aware comparings (eg. For GUI purposes ) , like german double-s or ß, use

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
String.Compare("Strasse", "Straße", true, ci)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you compare strings, you should use the methods that explicitly specify what kind of comparison you intend to perform. This makes your code much more maintainable and readable. Whenever possible, use the overloads of the methods of the System.String and System.Array classes that take a StringComparison enumeration parameter, so that you can specify which type of comparison to perform. It is best to avoid using the == and != operators when you compare strings. Also, avoid using the String.CompareTo instance methods because none of the overloads takes a StringComparison.

Depending on your needs, you can use on of the next methods:

```
bool result = root.Equals(root2, StringComparison.Ordinal);
result = root.Equals(root2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
bool areEqual = String.Equals(root, root2, StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

Source for this answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is [extensive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbh501kz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx) on MSDN that talks about *ordinal* and *culture-sensitive* string comparisons. *Ordinal* comparisons do not care about linguistics and, by default, will be concerned with case. *Culture-sensitive* comparisons do care about linguistics (cases, puncutation, etc).

This [article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-equals) on dotnetperls digs into the performance implications and even shows IL and benchmarks for the two methods of string comparison (`==` and `equals`).

And, finally, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175935/using-for-net-localized-string-comparison/8175990) shows that `==` is strictly an *ordinal* string comparison and not appropriate for *localized* strings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that practice is fine. You can also use [String.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx), and the comparison best practies found in [Best Pratices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx).

Yes, FxCop, will give warnings, but warnings are warnings. If you don't care about culture it's safe to ignore them. But, like real life warnings, it sometimes pays to heed them.

Answer (score 1):

If a string might be null or empty(aka "") you want to use string.IsNullOrEmpty(...);

Otherwise its fine in my book or most stuff. Depends on what your doing.