# Why .NET String.EqualsHelper seems to use half sized integers and longs

Tags: c#

Looking at the implementation of String.EqualsHelper and String.CompareOrdinalHelper (.NET 2 & 4), it seems to me that the comparisions are assuming that int byte size is 2 and long byte size is 4. I think the real sizes are 4 and 8 in the .NET 32-bit world. What am I missing? Is there any catch here? Source code sample in [A look inside the EqualsHelper method in the .NET framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5927545/1320384) and http://www.netframeworkdevs.com/common-language-runtime/string-comparision-24141.shtml.

Reverse engineered source from Reflector (Framework 2):

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
private static unsafe bool EqualsHelper(string strA, string strB)
{
    int length = strA.Length;
    if (length != strB.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    fixed (char* str = ((char*) strA))
    {
        char* chPtr = str;
        fixed (char* str2 = ((char*) strB))
        {
            char* chPtr2 = str2;
            char* chPtr3 = chPtr;
            char* chPtr4 = chPtr2;
            while (length >= 10)
            {
                if ((((*(((int*) chPtr3)) != *(((int*) chPtr4))) || (*(((int*) (chPtr3 + 2))) != *(((int*) (chPtr4 + 2))))) || ((*(((int*) (chPtr3 + 4))) != *(((int*) (chPtr4 + 4)))) || (*(((int*) (chPtr3 + 6))) != *(((int*) (chPtr4 + 6)))))) || (*(((int*) (chPtr3 + 8))) != *(((int*) (chPtr4 + 8)))))
                {
                    break;
                }
                chPtr3 += 10;
                chPtr4 += 10;
                length -= 10;
            }
            while (length > 0)
            {
                if (*(((int*) chPtr3)) != *(((int*) chPtr4)))
                {
                    break;
                }
                chPtr3 += 2;
                chPtr4 += 2;
                length -= 2;
            }
            return (length <= 0);
        }
    }
}

private static unsafe int CompareOrdinalHelper(string strA, string strB)
{
    int num = Math.Min(strA.Length, strB.Length);
    int num2 = -1;
    fixed (char* str = ((char*) strA))
    {
        char* chPtr = str;
        fixed (char* str2 = ((char*) strB))
        {
            char* chPtr2 = str2;
            char* chPtr3 = chPtr;
            char* chPtr4 = chPtr2;
            while (num >= 10)
            {
                if (*(((int*) chPtr3)) != *(((int*) chPtr4)))
                {
                    num2 = 0;
                    break;
                }
                if (*(((int*) (chPtr3 + 2))) != *(((int*) (chPtr4 + 2))))
                {
                    num2 = 2;
                    break;
                }
                if (*(((int*) (chPtr3 + 4))) != *(((int*) (chPtr4 + 4))))
                {
                    num2 = 4;
                    break;
                }
                if (*(((int*) (chPtr3 + 6))) != *(((int*) (chPtr4 + 6))))
                {
                    num2 = 6;
                    break;
                }
                if (*(((int*) (chPtr3 + 8))) != *(((int*) (chPtr4 + 8))))
                {
                    num2 = 8;
                    break;
                }
                chPtr3 += 10;
                chPtr4 += 10;
                num -= 10;
            }
            if (num2 == -1)
            {
                goto Label_0101;
            }
            chPtr3 += num2;
            chPtr4 += num2;
            int num3 = chPtr3[0] - chPtr4[0];
            if (num3 != 0)
            {
                return num3;
            }
            return (chPtr3[1] - chPtr4[1]);
        Label_00E7:
            if (*(((int*) chPtr3)) != *(((int*) chPtr4)))
            {
                goto Label_0105;
            }
            chPtr3 += 2;
            chPtr4 += 2;
            num -= 2;
        Label_0101:
            if (num > 0)
            {
                goto Label_00E7;
            }
        Label_0105:
            if (num > 0)
            {
                int num4 = chPtr3[0] - chPtr4[0];
                if (num4 != 0)
                {
                    return num4;
                }
                return (chPtr3[1] - chPtr4[1]);
            }
            return (strA.Length - strB.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all by the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
chPtr3 += 2;
```

This advances the pointer by four *bytes*, two *chars*.  A char is 2 bytes in .NET, it stores a character in utf-16 encoding.  Incrementing a char pointer advances it by one char, two bytes.

What's really going on here is the casts to int*.  Which makes the algorithm faster, comparing two characters at the same time.  Which works well on a 32-bit cpu, it has registers large enough to fit two characters (2 x 16 bits = 32 bits).  The part of the code that advances the pointer by 10 chars is equivalent to loop unrolling, a common optimization strategy to make loops faster.

The algorithm is specific to 32-bit code, the 64-bit version of mscorlib.dll uses a different approach that compares 4 chars at the same time with a single instruction.  Done with #if in [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,378)

Comment: The source code uses a different algorithm for 64-bit environment which, by the way, now I understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Char is two bytes.
Int is four bytes.
Int comparing compare four bytes or 2 chars on one comparing.

Operation 'char_pointer + 2' increment char pointer by 2 chars or 4 bytes.

Size of single incrementing (+4 bytes) is same as size of single comparing(+4 bytes)

Comment: Yes, this is what I think too. So why it increments the pointers only by half of that? The code above compares four bytes (bytes 0-3), for example, and increments by 2. Next turn it compares bytes (2-5), and son on. Note that bytes 2-3 are compared twice. Seems it does far more comparisions than needed. Thats my question... Why?